# FreeTDS can't read Servername from odbc.ini

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, odbc, freetds

I am trying to setup FreeTDS to connect into a mssql server in Ubuntu 14.04 and FreeTDS 4.2

However osql can't read **Servername** setting due unknow reasons. 
If I use isql, it works. However my programs use odbc.ini settings.

What I am doing wrong?

My odbc.ini;

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
Test = My Test Server

[mssql]
Description = My Test Server
Driver      = FreeTDS
Trace       = No
TDS_Version = 4.2
Servername  = mssql
```

Command

```
~$ osql -S mssql -U user -P password 
checking shared odbc libraries linked to isql for default directories...
strings: '': No hay tal fichero
    trying /tmp/sql ... no
    trying /tmp/sql ... no
    trying /etc ... OK
checking odbc.ini files
    reading /home/business/.odbc.ini
[mssql] not found in /home/business/.odbc.ini
    reading /etc/odbc.ini
[mssql] found in /etc/odbc.ini
found this section:
    [mssql]
    Description = My Test Server
    Driver      = FreeTDS
    Trace       = No
    TDS_Version = 4.2
    Servername  = mssql

looking for driver for DSN [mssql] in /etc/odbc.ini
  found driver line: "  Driver      = FreeTDS"
  driver "FreeTDS" found for [mssql] in odbc.ini
found driver named "FreeTDS"
"FreeTDS" is not an executable file
looking for entry named [FreeTDS] in /etc/odbcinst.ini
  found driver line: "  Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so"
  found driver /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so for [FreeTDS] in odbcinst.ini
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so is an executable file
Using ODBC-Combined strategy
DSN [mssql] has servername "" (from /etc/odbc.ini)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things you'll want to fix up here. First, in `odbc.ini`, is it "Server" and not "Servername". Here's an example.

odbc.ini:

```
[myserver]
Driver = FreeTDS
Server = myserver.mydomain.com
Port = 1433
TDS_Version = 7.2
```

freetds.conf:

```
[myserver]
host = myserver.mydomain.com
port = 1433
tds version = 7.2
```

Also, you're going to want to use a higher TDS Version. TDS 4.2 was for Microsoft SQL Server 6.0! Despite the documentation, I have found it does *not* work with all products. To select an appropriate TDS version, see here:

http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

You most likely want version 7.2 or 7.3. Good luck!